# SQL to get between conditions based on row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

OK crappy title, but I have a table with between conditions as rows.

```
id  | Value |  ValueMax
 1        0       49000
 2    50000       70000
```

The easy part is comparing a value and returning one of the rows.  The part that breaks is that if it goes over the ValueMax, in this case the 70000, it should return that row.  But the simple condition x > ValueMax also satisfies the other row and both are returned.  What am I missing.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore `ValueMax` and just use `ValueMin`.  In ANSI SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where @x >= ValueMin
order by ValueMin desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Different databases have different ways of spelling "fetch first 1 row only"; some use `limit`, some use `top`, some use `rownum`, and several even support this ANSI syntax.

Comment: Should the `order by` be `desc`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Value, ValueMax
FROM mytable
WHERE @x BETWEEN Value AND ValueMax

UNION

SELECT Id, Value, ValueMax
FROM mytable
WHERE ValueMax = (SELECT MAX(ValueMax) FROM mytable) AND   
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable
                  WHERE @x BETWEEN Value AND ValueMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing data redundantly as ValueMax is always the next record's value minus 1. You could compute ValueMax in a query:

```
select
  value,
  lead(value) over (order by value) - 1 as valuemax
from mytable;
```

This even corrects the last record which now gets a null for "unlimited" instead of some wrong number (70000 in your example).

This query gets you the correct record for a value @x accordingly:

```
select value, valuemax
from
(
  select
    value,
    lead(value) over (order by value) - 1 as valuemax
  from mytable
) values
where @x between value and coalesce(valuemax, @x);
```

You can remove ValueMax from your table. It is redundant as shown and thus not needed.

If you want to keep this column for convenience, then you should set the last value to null (why is it 70000 anyway when it must be ignored)? That would simplify the query to:

```
select value, valuemax
from mytable
where @x between value and coalesce(valuemax, @x);
```